# if the number is divisible by 3 print A and if it divisible by 5 print B and if it is divisible by both print C without using more than 2 if statement

Tags: dart, division

if the number is divisible by 3 print A and if it is divisible by 5 print B and if it is divisible by both print C without using more than 2 if the statement (dart will be preferred)

Comment: Is the ternary operator considered an if statement?

Comment: Consider https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62070/26523

Comment: This is the FizzBuzz problem (except that your forgot to say what to print if neither divisble by 3 nor 5). It's a standard industry test problem, there are lots of available solutions in any language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this in dart by using ternary operator (but this also works as if-else statement).

Example:

```
int a = 3;

a%3==0 && a%5==0?
 print("C"):
 a%5==0?
 print("B"):
 a%3==0?
 print("A"):
 print("not divisible by 3 and 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  test(1);
  test(2);
  test(3);
  test(4);
  test(5);
  test(10);
  test(15);
}

void test(int i) {
  final by5 = i % 5 == 0;
  final by3 = i % 3 == 0;
  switch ((by5 ? 2 : 0) + (by3 ? 1 : 0)) {
    case 1:
      print('$i: A');
      break;
    case 2:
      print('$i: B');
      break;
    case 3:
      print('$i: C');
      break;
    default:
      print('$i: Neither');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1: Neither
2: Neither
3: A
4: Neither
5: B
10: B
15: C
```